# SQL Server - Insert fallido no da error si tiene un trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert

tengo una tabla que tiene un disparador que ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado tras una inserción de datos. El problema se se reproduce cuando el insert falla. En este caso si existe el trigger, la ejecución SQL no da error. Simplemente devuelve un *The statement has been terminated.* No obstante, si no existe el trigger, devuelve correctamete un código de error, como por ejemplo, *String or binary data would be truncated.*
Sería necesario, ejecutar el trigger, pero si el insert da error, que se pare la ejecución y de error.

```
--DROP TRIGGER dbo.nombre_trigger
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER dbo.nombre_trigger
    ON dbo.nombre_tabla
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
    @campo BIGINT = (SELECT campo FROM inserted)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    exec nombre_procedure @parametro=@campo;

END
GO
```

¿Alguna idea para que si el insert falla, se devuelva error? Muchas gracias

*Actualización:* El problema parece que se da en que el trigger es ejecutado aún cuando el insert falla y la aplicación que ejecutó la query se queda con el resultado del trigger que no falló, el cual simplemente no tenía datos sobre los que actuar al fallar el insert, y por eso devuelve ok.

Comment: Parece que tienes el trigger incompleto. Concretamente, ¿qué deseas que haga el trigger? Gracias y un saludo

Comment: El trigger solo debe ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado, el que se muestra al final del trigger. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

mira la verdad no se si te sirva pero intenta esto.

```
--Creacion del trigger
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.nombre_trigger
    ON dbo.nombre_tabla
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
    @campo BIGINT = (SELECT campo FROM inserted)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If @parametro = @campo
      Begin
          exec nombre_procedure;
      End

END
GO
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias, aunque no resolvería el problema y tampoco funcionaría el código en este caso. Esto se debe a que ya no se estaría pasando el _@campo_ como parámetro al procedure, si no que ahora se estaría usando el _@parametro_ como una nueva variable que no se declara. Hay que pasar el _@campo_ como parámetro al procedure. He actualizado la explicación para que pueda ser más claro el problema que se genera.